# Shell script runs manually but not executed through cron job

Tags: linux, centos, cron, cron-task

I am using a shell script to delete log files in my Linux machine. And I have used crontab to execute this job periodically. I can execute this script manually and see it is working fine. But the script is not triggered through cron job.

Shell script:

> [root@testVM-dev log]# vim /path_to_dir/log_cleanup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$(date)
echo "Cron Job to delete log files start...@ $now" | tee -a /path_to_dir/log/cronjob_log.log

/usr/bin/find /path_to_dir/log/localhost_access_log.* -type f -mtime +5 -print -delete | tee -a /path_to_dir/log/cronjob_log.log

echo "Delete files completed!" | tee -a /path_to_dir/log/cronjob_log.log
```

crontab entry: (Runs every minute)

```
[root@testVM-dev log]# crontab -l
*/1 * * * * root /path_to_dir/log_cleanup.sh
```

Also I have checked in cron logs that the job is executed every minute. But I couldn't see any logs in the targeted log file "cronjob_log.log"

cron logs:

> vim /var/log/cron

```
Jul 16 03:56:01 rstestVM-dev crond[19131]: (root) CMD (root /path_to_dir/log_cleanup.sh)
Jul 16 03:57:01 rstestVM-dev crond[19150]: (root) CMD (root /path_to_dir/log_cleanup.sh)
Jul 16 03:58:01 rstestVM-dev crond[19168]: (root) CMD (root /path_to_dir/log_cleanup.sh)
Jul 16 03:59:01 rstestVM-dev crond[19188]: (root) CMD (root /path_to_dir/log_cleanup.sh)
```

Can someone help me on what is going wrong here?

Comment: can you increase the interval a bit to see as to what is exactly going on

Comment: Do you mean to increase the frequency from 1 min to more (like 5 mins or so)?

Comment: yes , try adding it to 5 minutes and then see

Comment: Changed frequency to 5 mins and still it behaves same. */5 * * * * root /path_to_dir/log_cleanup.sh  ... .log.... Jul 16 04:45:01 rstestVM-dev crond[20423]: (root) CMD (root /path_to_dir/log_cleanup.sh)
Jul 16 04:50:01 rstestVM-dev crond[20527]: (root) CMD (root /path_to_dir/log_cleanup.sh)

Comment: can you try changing now=$(date) to now=$date and see if it works

Comment: Actually I have removed the date variable itself now. Still it didn't execute that script.But I can see in logs that it calls the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. That I have removed the user from crontab entry & it worked.

Original crontab entry:

```
[root@testVM-dev log]# crontab -l
*/1 * * * * root /path_to_dir/log_cleanup.sh
```

After modification:

```
[root@testVM-dev log]# crontab -l
*/1 * * * * /path_to_dir/log_cleanup.sh
```

Now I got confused why the user entry in cron job didn't work? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Besides manually specifying value of `PATH`, try specifying the path to `tee` and `date`.

`/usr/bin/date`, `/usr/bin/tee`

Comment: Let me check. Thanks.. :)

Comment: It didn't work. I removed date and gave full path to /usr/bin/tee. But still I face same issue..